# Color notation in gradle html dependency report

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

What is the color notation in gradle html report. I referred api docs of gradle but did not get any answer.

For suppose, below is my html report, what is the difference between orange and black.

[image]

Comment: Looks like cases where there was a version conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This orange color, along with the arrow pointing to a different version, means that there was a conflict between two versions, that has been resolved by choosing the version on the right.

There is another color being used, but if you see it, it means the dependency was unresolvable (so it shouldn't happen often).